# Display array in Block List in ruby

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

Imagine I have array of values ranging from 1 to 24. I want to populate these values in an HTML table as shown below.

HTML Table

`|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |

|  7  |  8  |  9  |  10 |  11 |  12 |

|  13 |  14 |  15 |  16 |  17 |  18 |

|  19 |  20 |  21 |  22 |  23 |  24 |`

Can anybody help me in figuring out how to loop through an array in ruby and populate these values? I am using ruby 1.8.7.

P.S Sorry about representing the HTML table in an ugly way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [each_slice](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_slice):

```
1.8.7 (main):0 > (1..24).each_slice(6).each {|b| p b }
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
[13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
[19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
```

Comment: Thanks !! Im marking your answer as correct even though I have posted the exact code i was looking for below.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an actual representation of what I exactly needed which is totally based on lucapette's answer. Thanks to him.

```
<table>

    <% (1..24).each_slice(6).each do | num |    %>
    <tr>    
    <% num.each do |n| %>
        <td> <%= n %></td>
     <% end %>
    </tr>
     <% end %>
</table>
```